# Why in apache conf, the file "database.php.default" is not named as "database.php"?

Tags: php, apache

In apache conf, there is only one database confg file. But still why it is named as database.php.default and not simply as database.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's bad practice to commit real usernames, passwords, and connection information into your version control system. If you just ignored that file from commits, nobody would know that missing file is required.

Answer (score 1):

Because it shows you the default configurations, you're supposed to copy it to database.php with your personal settings

Comment: Thank You so much. that clarifies.